# Shell sorting with specific format

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk

My database is structured in this format, and I need to sort it by the 6th column.

```
10027|Chen|Ning|female|1982-12-08|2010-02-22T17:59:59.221+0000|1.2.9.86|Firefox
10995116908|Chen|Wei|female|1985-08-02|2010-05-2420:52:26.582+0000|27.98.244.108|Firefox
```

*(note on the T in the 6th column)*

So far I have tried to, by `sort -M` and specifically `sort -k 6M -t "|" "file.dat"` or `sort -k6 -M -t "|"` etc.

The desired sort output from this

```
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Do|Hα» ChΓ­|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
```

must be this

```
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox 
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
4194|Do|Hα» ChΓ­|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: show how are you specifying *a given dateA to another given dateB*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest propably date A 2010-02-15T09:33:33.400+0000 ,since it has not been specified to us either, to dateB 2010-03-16T20:20:20.300+0000

Comment: @Cyrus yes my bad , I did

Comment: what if there will be date `2010-01-01T09:33:33.400+0000`? accounting to your given date `2010-02-15T09:33:33.400+0000`

Comment: That was my arbitrary choice for dateA meaning any date after that. Even if there is no such exact date

Comment: @Cyrus then those entries in the database wont be outputted

Comment: are `dateA` and `dateB` supposed to act as search parameters (eg, display only rows with field 6 between `dateA` and `dateB`)? and if so, can they be empty/undefined?  are they always defined in format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sss+HHMM` ?

Comment: will all records in the file have the same timezone offset (eg, `+0000` in the sample data)?  if different timezone offsets could exist in the same file, are you expecting all data to be converted to the same timezone for search/sorting purposes?

Comment: @markp all the records have the same timezone offset

and yes `dateA` and `dateB` are search parameters.

If one is empty / not given in the executable order 

`./tool.sh --born-since  dateA -f file.dat` then it must display rows with a date > than dateA and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I don't see nothing special in this task - just simple sorting:

```
sort -k6,6 -t "|" file.dat
```

The output:

```
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
4194|Do|Hα» ChΓ­|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
```

Comment: Thanks that worked , although i thought that -M option was needed.

Comment: `-M` is for month sort, not for the whole datetime

Answer (score 0):

Added a couple extra data lines to make search examples a bit easier to see:

```
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
4194|Do|H? Ch?|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
4567|Kim|Lisa|female|1982-05-29|2009-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
1234|Axe|John|male|1982-05-29|2012-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
```

I'll define a `bash` script [`search.sh`] with the following input parameters:

```
search.sh [--born_after <dateA>] [--born_before <dateB>] -f <dbfile>

`--born_after  <dateA>` : [optional] search for data records with field6 >= this search parameter; [format=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sss+HHMM] [default=0000-00-00T00:00:00.000+0000]
`--born_before <dateB>` : [optional] search for data records with field6 <= this search parameter; [format=YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sss+HHMM] [default=9999-99-99T99:99:99.999+9999]
`-f <dbfile>`           : [required] data file to search
```

The actual script:

```
$ cat search.sh
#!/bin/bash

# set default search dates, clear the dbfile variable:

dateA="0000-00-00T00:00:00.000+0000"
dateB="9999-99-99T99:99:99.999+9999"

unset dbfile

# simulate getopts so we can parse for long and short option names

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
        case $1 in
                --born-after)   dateA=$2                                   ; shift  ;;
                --born-before)  dateB=$2                                   ; shift  ;;
                -f)             dbfile=$2                                  ; shift  ;;
                *)              echo "Unexpected argument '$1'. Aborting." ; exit 1 ;;
        esac

        shift
done

# if we didn't get receive/parse a `-f <dbfile>` option then abort:

[[ "${dbfile}" = '' ]] && echo "Missing a dbfile. Aborting." && exit 1

# start by sorting dbfile using RomanPerekhrest's solution; then pipe results to
# an awk script to handle the 'search'

sort -k6,6 -t "|" ${dbfile} | awk -F"|" -v dateA="${dateA}" -v dateB="${dateB}" '$6>=dateA && $6<=dateB'
```

- `-v date[AB]="${date[AB]}"` : pass our bash variables into the awk script; for simplicity sake we'll keep the same names
- `-F "|"` : define input field separator for awk
- `$6>=dateA && $6<=dateB` : only print lines where field6 is between (inclusive) our search dates

Some sample runs of the script:

```
# no search dates provided (ie, use defaults; display entire file (sorted))
$ search.sh -f file.dat
4567|Kim|Lisa|female|1982-05-29|2009-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
4194|Do|H? Ch?|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
1234|Axe|John|male|1982-05-29|2012-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox

# only print records (sorted) with field6 >= 2009-10-01
$ search.sh --born-after '2009-10-01T00:00:00.000+0000' -f file.dat
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
4194|Do|H? Ch?|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
1234|Axe|John|male|1982-05-29|2012-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox

# only print records (sorted) with field6 between 2009-10-01 and 2011-05-05
$ search.sh --born-after '2009-10-01T00:00:00.000+0000' --born-before '2011-05-05T23:59:59.999+9999' -f file.dat
8698|Liu|Chen|female|1982-05-29|2010-02-21T08:44:41.479+0000|14.103.81.196|Firefox
1129|Lepland|Carmen|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
8333|Wang|Chen|female|1980-02-02|2010-03-15T10:21:43.365+0000|1.4.16.148|Internet Explorer
933|Perera|Mahinda|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
4194|Do|H? Ch?|male|1988-10-14|2010-03-17T22:46:17.657+0000|103.10.89.118|Internet Explorer
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver , and alhtough it works perfectly for small databases , when i handle big files it doen't work like it should. Should I check more complicated things like the compiler or the shell instance/version?

Comment: You'd have to expand on the comment "it doesn't work like it should"; also, if you're normally searching for a (relatively) small number of rows, it should be a bit more efficient if you perform the `awk` work first, with the output then piped to `sort` (net result is that you would spend less resources sorting a smaller data set)

Comment: something else to think about ... if you're always sorting this file by field6 ... consider sorting it once and saving the results to a new file, then run your searches against the new/sorted file (ie, eliminate the overhead of repeatedly sorting the original file)